# How to change the "src" attribute of an underlying element

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css-selectors

I've got the following HTML (WordPress)
[image: HTML Code]

I hardcoded the ID into it
`id="liva-logo`

But this is not best practice in WordPress, because I loose this once every theme update.

I use some jQuery to change the img `src` if when on certain pages.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("livathome") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("eigendom") > -1) {
       jQuery("#liva-logo").attr("src","/uploads/Logo-livathome-retina.png");
    }
});
```

So you can see that I select the `#liva-logo`

I was wondering if I could select the upper level div class `"logo-desktop"` and apply my jQuery to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  You can use jquery to select child elements.  Its just a matter of choosing the right filter:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if([your if clause]) {
       jQuery(".logo-desktop img").attr("src","yournewsource.jpg");
    }
}
```

JQuery has lots of options for [selecting elements](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp).  In this case, you could use `.logo.logo-desktop img` or `.logo>a>img` ...  it all depends on how complex the page structure is.

In general, most of us use a combination of css class  (the "." selector) and element type (eg - "img", "a", "div", etc) to select the right element(s).

You can also check the LENGTH of the result you get in javascript to see if the selector you used acutally returns anything:

```
var myImage = $('.logo-desktop img');
if(myImage.length==0) { 
    //length==0 means your selector returned 0 elements
}
```

Hope all that helps!

Comment: Simple as that, I should've know this. Tunnelvision I guess!

Answer (score 1):

You could use this selector:

```
jQuery(".logo.logo-desktop > a > img").attr(      [...]
```

Comment: Thanks! Very quick response! It was simple, guess I had tunnelvision; Still learning!